# Passing a bounded method in Cython as argument

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am trying to wrap some C++ code into Cython and I came up with some trouble trying to pass a method from a class as an argument to a function.

I do not know if it makes it more clear, but class A represents a statistical model (so myAMethod uses not only the arguments passed but many instance variables) and B has different methods for minimizing the function passed.

In C++ I have something of this style:

`class A
{
public:
    double myAMethod(double*)
};
class B
{
public:
    double myBMethod(A&, double (A::*f) (double*)
}`

So what I am trying to do is to use instances of both A and B in Cython code. I had no trouble wrapping the classes, but when I try to use myBMethod, I don't know how to pass a pointer of the kind `A::*myAMethod`

If I do this:
`myBMethod(ptrToAObj[0], &ptrToAObj.myAMethod)`, 
then Cython compiles this code to `[...] &ptrToAObj->myAMethod [...]`, and I get the message one would expect from g++:

> "ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function."

But if I try to point straight to the class method, and do `myBMethod(ptrToAObj[0], A.myAMethod)`, then Cython won't compile and say that

> myAMethod is not a static member from A.

And that's pretty much all I was able to advance. I could work at C++ level and avoid any of these anoyances, but if I were able to use instances of A and B in Python (via Cython) interactively, it would help me in speedig my development pace.
Any help will be really appreciated, and I apologize if this question as been already answered and/or is available in a referece - I search SO, Cython reference and Smith's "Cython" book and I did not found this theme adressed.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a partial (if horrendous) solution. I'm prepared to believe there's a better way, but I don't know it.

In cpp_bit.hpp:

```
class A { 
  public:
    double myAMethod(double*) { return 0.0; }
}; 

typedef double (A::*A_f_ptr)(double *);

class B {
 public:
   double myBMethod(A& a, A_f_ptr f) { 
     double x = 0.1;
     return (a.*f)(&x);
   }
};

A_f_ptr getAMethod() {
  return &A::myAMethod;
}
```

I've given the functions very basic implementations, just so I can check for really obvious crashes. I've also created a function pointer which returns a pointer to `myAMethod`. You'll need to do this for every method you want to wrap.

In py_bit.pyx

```
# distutils: language = c++

from cython.operator import dereference

cdef extern from "cpp_bit.hpp":
  cdef cppclass A:
    double myAMethod(double*)

  cdef cppclass A_f_ptr:
    pass

  cdef cppclass B:
    double myBMethod(A&, A_f_ptr)

  cdef A_f_ptr getAMethod()

cdef class PyA:
  cdef A* thisptr
  def __cinit__(self):
    self.thisptr = new A()
  def __dealloc__(self):
    del self.thisptr
  cpdef myAMethod(self,double[:] o):
    return self.thisptr.myAMethod(&o[0])

cdef class PyB:
  cdef B* thisptr
  def __cinit__(self):
    self.thisptr = new B()
  def __dealloc__(self):
    del self.thisptr
  cpdef myBMethod(self,PyA a):
    return self.thisptr.myBMethod(dereference(a.thisptr),getAMethod())
```

I couldn't figure out how to typedef a member function pointer in Cython, so instead I created an empty cppclass with the same name. This works because cython just seems to use it for type-checking and nothing more, and since it includes cpp_bit.hpp (where it's defined) you can use it no problem.

All I've done is left the task of getting the member function pointer to c++ (in `getAMethod`, which I call). I don't think it's entirely satisfactory, but it looks workable, and is only a short extra c++ function for every member function you want to access. You could play with where you put it to encapsulate it more cleanly.

**An alternative, untested approach:** (Edit: further thought suggests this might be very tricky! Attempt this at your own risk!)

Personally, I'd be tempted to change the c++ interface so that `myBMethod` is defined as

```
double myBMethod(std::function<double (double*)>)
```

(since presumably you always call it with the `A` instance it's passed with). Then use lambda functions in c++(11!) to wrap the A instance and function together

```
b.myBMethod([&](double* d){ return a.myAMethod(d) };
```

It may then take a bit of hugely complicated Cython wrapping that I haven't yet considered, but it should be possible to convert a simple `double (double*)` function pointer to the c++ function object, and so use it more directly.

It's also possible that your actual design is more complicated in ways I haven't considered, and this approach isn't flexible enough anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It works perfectly well for me. You are being too harsh calling it horrendous! If I had learnt something in my short period using cython, is that wrapping a C++ class usually gets as messy as it can XD.
I am new to python, so I didn't know if I could get an analogous type to double (A::*) (double*), since the void* + getter strategy also does this job, I'll keep it.
Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: So, I realised that I gave some bad advice. The internet reliably informs me that you can't necessarily store a member function pointer in `void*`. As it is, it almost doesn't matter (since in my example code Cython only used void* for "type checking") and never for storage, but you could easily write code where it goes wrong. I've changed it to define an empty `cppclass` as an alternative to typedef, which I think basically does the right thing - it creates a type that Cython knows of, but knows nothing about...

Comment: Wow, thanks for the warning! In my code I was only trying to "fool" Cython in its code-checking, but it is usually safer to avoid void pointers (at least for me), so this advice is really helpful. Thanks!